# Install Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, pop-os

I have 128GB M.2 SSD and on the remaining HDD (which is 1 TB with 3 partitions - 1st with 500GB, second with 380GB and the third with 100GB) I want to install PopOS on the second partition. This HDD contained Windows installation so I formatted that partition. (note that I formatted only the C drive, now I use that partition for storage with the SSD, and the third partition is for storage, but for things I do not need that much but I will in the future)

I flashed the ISO on 16GB Flash drive using Etcher, but when I booted the USB, the installation couldn't finalize. It said that it failed due to a hardware error. I changed the boot priority on the HDD over the SSD (first to boot from the HDD) and the same error. I flashed the ISO again using Rufus and the same problem, again.

Both my SSD and HDD are GPT, but the BIOS is set up to Legacy mode. I changed it to UEFI but when I booted the Flash drive it said boot the kernel first so I disabled UEFI.

Then I deleted the remaining Healthy partition from the previous Windows 10, so that there were only 3 partitions left. I created only root partition for the PopOS and it failed because there were not BIOS boot partition..

Then, I created one partition and set it to bios_grub, and the installation finished! Normally it displays to restart or shut down the computer. I restarted it and booted directly in the Windows 10..... I restarted again and booted manually into the HDD, but again, the same problem, I booted into the Windows 10. So now, I don't know what to do.

Also I am using Lenovo V310 15isk.
I've been trying for the past 3/4 days and I'm tired, I don't know what to do, and I want very much PopOS, but if I can't install I will try with elementaryOS. Also, I am using Linux in school, but never installed one.
Any suggestions to help me?

Comment: Side note: "Alongside" instead on different drives almost always leads to problems.

Comment: well, when I look at it again you are right, however, what can cause the problem and how to fix it